# Passwords get lost after deployment

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, deployment, web, passwords

I manage an ASP.NET MVC 3 website with multiple users. Every user have a password that gets saved by their browser when they log into the site. Over the past months, I have made multiple deployments of that website to correct bugs or implement new features, all without any problems.

With that said, this week, when I deployed the site as usual, all users lost their saved passwords in their browsers. The login name is still kept in memory, but the password has been lost. There has been no changes to anything to do with the login system at all for months and it is the first time that the passwords are lost.

I have tried to search for a possibility that would explain this problem but to no avail. Do you have any idea what would explain this problem?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you sure nothing was pushed to thier desktops that just happen to coincide with your update?

Comment: How is the password saved by the browser? Is it in the browser's normal password remember function? Is it stored as a cookie (possibly with en expiry date)? Is this a corporate environment where updates and policies are pushed to the clients simultaneously?

Comment: @AndersAbel Thank you for your reply. My users are not from a corporate environment, so nothing is pushed to them. I am not saving the password myself in a cookie, the browser is saving the password. The only cookie that I am using is the ASP.NET authentication cookie that I emit after the user has correctly logged in. I do not see how it could have an impact. Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suspect the cookies in this case; either they expired (after a set length of time) and it just happened to co-incide with your deployment. Or in your deployment you changed the cookie name / path etc. such that now the browser cannot validate the user.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a few reasons:

1.If the password or user name text box name changes, then the browser will disassociate the login with the web site.

original syntax in razor:

@Html.PasswordFor(model => model.**Password**)

new password box:

@Html.PasswordFor(model => model.**MyPassword**)

2.If the view changes name or the login occurs in a new view then the browser will disassociate the password with the web site

3.You also need to check the expiration of the browser cache.

4.Check for security updates on the browser

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I suspected points 1 and 2 also, but after verifying, I noticed that the none of the textbox names were changed and neither was the view name. My users are not from a corporate environment, so nothing is pushed to them. I am not saving the password myself in a cookie, the browser is saving the password. The only cookie that I am using is the ASP.NET authentication cookie that I emit after the user has correctly logged in. I do not see how it could have an impact. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Do you have an SSL certificate for the login?